# SKShapeNode with swift for iOS 7.1

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ios7, skspritenode

after coding a game for iOS 8 with swift I decided to test it on iOS 7.1.

First I got an error for initializing  SKLabelNode like this:

```
var myLabel: SKLabelNode = SKLabelNode(text: "test")
```

I corrected it to work with iOS 7.1 like this

```
var myLabel: SKLabelNode = SKLabelNode()
myLabel.text = "test"
```

Unfortunately I do not know how to do the same fix with my SKShapeNodes

My code:

```
var myShapeNode: SKShapeNode = SKShapeNode(rect: myRect)
```

How can I make my rectangular SKShapeNode work with iOS 7.1?
I tried using the myShapeNode.path but it did not work out...

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not gave the example of how you work with Path, but the example below should work well for IOS 7.1 (in this case CGRectMake is equivalent to your myRect)

```
let rect: SKShapeNode = SKShapeNode()
let path = CGPathCreateMutable()
CGPathAddRect(path, nil, CGRectMake(0,0,100,100))
rect.path = path
```

Comment: This worked and got rid of the error. My App starts and is running. There are still a few bugs that are not there with iOS 8... But thats another story. 

Thanks for your help!